# What's the significance of "//" and "/" in the script tag?

Tags: html, angularjs, leaflet

For instance, I am confused with understanding "//" from "//unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"and "/" from "/js/ui-leaflet.min.js"

Comment: `//` is `http://` or `https://` dependent on the current page schema, whilst `/` is just an absoute path

Comment: To add to the comment above, "`//` is `http://` or `https://`"... Which one is chosen depends on the scheme (http/https) of the containing page.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Protocol-relative_URLs

Answer (score 1):

The `//` at the start of a resource url is an implicit protocol which tells the browser to use the same protocol as the current page i.e. `http` or `https`.

If you are on a page at https://www.example.org a script src of `//unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js` will load `https://unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js`.

If you are on a page at http://www.example.org a script src of `//unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js` will load `http://unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js`.

A script src of `/unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js` would mean the browser loads the script from the implicit domain name i.e. `http://www.example.org` which would translate to `http://www.example.org/unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js`. If used incorrectly this can stop external resources loading. This should be used for resources located at the same hostname.

You can read more about URLs at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Comment: Is there a difference in how the browser interprets and handles this? Wouldn't both maintain the same scheme + host + port as the containing page?

Comment: Browsers should handle this as mentioned above. So the browser would not change the scheme between `http` and `https` unless the destination performs a redirect.